# The placement order of __attribute__((section("name")))

Tags: gcc, arm

I am using a code example where I have this define:

```
#define PLACE_IN_SECTION( __x__ )  __attribute__((section (__x__)))
```

all over the code.

e.g.

```
     //file1.cpp
PLACE_IN_SECTION("A") static int a1;
    

    //file2.cpp
PLACE_IN_SECTION("A") static int a2;
```

I can't find information regarding the order the variables are placed in a specific section.
Keil just told me to put everything in a struct to have control over the addresses.
But I still want to know if there is any rule regarding the order, per compiler.

So basically the question is who will be first, and why?

Using both gcc, and arm compiler (v6)

Edit:
This variables are shard with another CPU, and the address they get matter to the system.

Comment: Just very silly question from me... sorry... But why on Earth you should care about order at all ? If you are up to particular order (for unknown reason), place them in separate sections and order by means of linker script

Comment: The address of the variables is important in that code, it is shared with another CPU, that I have no control of .

Comment: `the order the variables are placed in a specific section` is unspecified. They are put in any order linker wants them to. `The address of the variables` Then place each variable in its own section.

Comment: If you want ensure precise order, either place variables in different sections and set addresses in linker script, or place all of them in one section and in one file ordering respectively. Otherwise you are just playing guessing game with particular version of toolchain linker.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to the compiler to decide order of variables in memory. Different versions of the same compiler can give different order on the same code.

To retain order the variables as in the source, GCC has optimization flag `-fno-toplevel-reorder`

> Do not reorder top-level functions, variables, and asm statements. Output them in the same order that they appear in the input file. When this option is used, unreferenced static variables are not removed. This option is intended to support existing code that relies on a particular ordering. For new code, it is better to use attributes when possible.

> -ftoplevel-reorder is the default at -O1 and higher, and also at -O0 if -fsection-anchors is explicitly requested. Additionally -fno-toplevel-reorder implies -fno-section-anchors.

[link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

This might reduce quality of optimization. To prevent it globaly, the variables, that must be placed in a known order, should be moved to a separate file, which is compiled with this option.